# Mocking VB.NET Methods With Moq

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to unit test a controller action that uses the membership provider to update user details.  I am using Moq which so far has been easy to use.

The problem is I can't seem to get it to mock calls to methods that don't return anything.

```
<TestMethod()> _
Public Sub Can_Update_User()
  ' Arrange
  _membershipService.Setup(Function(x) x.UpdateUser(It.IsAny(Of MembershipUser)))
  Dim controller As New UsersController(_membershipService.Object, _roleProvider.Object, _supportWorksService.Object, _portalClientService.Object)
  ' Act
  Dim result As ViewResult = controller.Edit("testUser", New FormCollection)
  ' Assert
  Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName)
End Sub
```

The setup of the mocked membership service won't compile, the error is:

> Overload resolution failed because no
>   accessible 'Setup' can be called with
>   these arguments:
>
> 'Public Function
>   Setup(Of TResult)(expression As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService,
>   TResult))) As
>   Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService,
>   TResult)': Expression does not produce
>   a value.
>
> 'Public Function Setup(Of
>   TResult)(expression As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService,
>   TResult))) As
>   Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService,
>   TResult)': Data type(s) of the type
>   parameter(s) cannot be inferred from
>   these arguments. Specifying the data
>   type(s) explicitly might correct this
>   error.
>
> 'Public Function
>   Setup(expression As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Action(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService))) As
>   Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup(Of
>   Services.IMembershipService)':
>   Expression does not produce a value.

What have I missed?  Am I going to have to create a fake class rather than use Moq any time my class has a method I want to call on it?

Edit:

Ok, a little reading around suggests this is due to the way lambdas are expressed in VB using Function() which must have a result.

Has anyone found a work around for this or am I going to have to ditch Moq for faking methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've found, the current version of VB.NET (VB9) only allows lambda methods that return a value (ie. `Function` lambdas). There's not really much you can do about that other than to [create a function to return a dummy value](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/3729301). I can't test it at the moment, so I'm not sure that is a viable workaround for this case.

In the [next version of VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28VS.100%29.aspx) (VB10), the language will support `Sub` lambdas and should help in these cases.

It seems other people are also [having trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798570/experiences-using-moq-with-vb-net) of differing degrees with the current Moq/VB.NET combination.

Comment: :(  Shame really, apart from this I'm really loving Moq.  If I suggest to the boss we put off development for another year so that they can get VB10 out I think he'll kill me!

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio 2010 use

```
serviceMock.Setup(Sub(c) c.MethodName(paramName))
```

Also, make sure that the mocked entity (`serviceMock`) is either mocked as an interface, or has MethodName declared as overrideable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798570/experiences-using-moq-with-vb-net) seals the deal.

Kind a dissapointing - investigation took me quite a lot of time. :/

Answer (score 0):

Typemock has support for VB.NET friendly API for that purpose:
http://site.typemock.com/vbpage/2009/9/10/unit-testing-vbnet.html

Comment: Unfortunately as a small group of internal developers we can't justify the cost of TypeMock.  Currently we are just writing methods we need to mock as functions that return a boolean and waiting for VB10.