# Would it be recommended to write Test in C# and production code in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, tdd, moq

After some hours creating a vb.net helper class for unit-tests and integrating moq into the project followed by a smashing hit on the "Run tests" Key-Command and then a Red Light revealed himself.

To save you the trouble of what happened. The answer that explained the problem can be found here : 
[Experiences using moq with VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798570/experiences-using-moq-with-vb-net)

So i tough hey lets just write the test in C# ! (type mock is not an option)

After 15 min a shiny green light while the vb.net test still fails.

Would it be recommended to continue writing test in C# with a mocking framework.
Or just implement for each Real-Interface a Fake-Interface in vb.net

Some constraints on the freedom are :

- production code must be in visual basic
- They don't know what TDD is so i shouldn't be writing test but then again thats like putting yourself ready to fall into the debug-nightmare cliff again.

Or is there an alternative approach to this?

Also my apologizes for my not so great English writing style (I am working on it)
[image: C# succeeds where vb.net fails]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as your VB.NET code is `CLSCompliant` you shouldn't run into any problems. But if you are using some VB.NET specific features such as `Optional` then it might get awkward.

> r just implement for each
>   Real-Interface a Fake-Interface in
>   vb.net

Don't to that, it's just waste of time.

Comment: I have a look into CLSCompliant.

Comment: In what ways are optional parameters specific to VB.NET? C# 4 has them, too...!? Do the concrete implementations in C# and VB.NET actually differ at the CLI level?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to write code in VB.NET that isn't CLSCompliant.  Optional certainly doesn't matter, it just isn't optional to another language.

Comment: @Hans, @stakx "Optional" in VB.NET is not CLSCompliant, at least for 3.5 yes code differs in IL level

Comment: @hans I believe it is possible to write non compliant VB. The MSDN page  "writing ClsCompliant code" has a VB code sample that gives a compiler warning about non-compliance with ClsCompliant. Therefore, the compiler is saying it isn't compliant.[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ - Ah, I forgot about the unsigned integer support.  Thanks :)